# Installing RedCloth with RubyGems issue

Tags: ruby

I've just attempted to install RedCloth on my Mac and this is what i got

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> Successfully installed RedCloth-4.2.9
>
> Parsing documentation for RedCloth-4.2.9
>
> unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ../../extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/RedCloth-4.2.9/redcloth_scan.bundle, skipping
>
> unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_attributes.o, skipping
>
> unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_inline.o, skipping
>
> unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_scan.bundle, skipping
>
> unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_scan.o, skipping
>
> unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/redcloth_scan.bundle, skipping
>
> 1 gem installed

What could be the problem and how can i get RedCloth installed?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using and are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
and i think rvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it actually did install. You're getting those errors from the documentation.

Do a

```
gem list | grep -i redcloth
```

to make sure it's there.

Try installing without the documentation:

```
gem install RedCloth --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

*Update*: To fix the issue properly, try:

```
gem update rdoc
```

Comment: also i tried to run a rb test file with require 'RedCloth' and that gave me an error

Comment: /Users/Ryder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- RedCloth (LoadError)
 from /Users/Ryder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from rubygemtesting.rb:2:in `<main>'

This is the error i get when i tried to run the test file

Comment: Can you try this: gem install RedCloth --no-ri --no-rdoc

Comment: That is just not installing the documentation when it installs the gem which is where it seemed to be tripping up. The question is why? Can you tell me what the output of: echo $LC_CTYPE is?

Comment: Also in IRB. What is the output of Encoding.default_internal and Encoding.default_external?

Comment: echo $LC_CTYPE resulted with blank
Encoding.default_internal returned nil

Comment: and Encoding.default_external returned  => #<Encoding:UTF-8>

Comment: As to why you're getting the parsing errors. My guess is that it is your rubygems version. What is the output of gem --version

Comment: See my updated answer. I *think* updating rdoc will fix the issue for you.

Comment: well i tried and installed hpricot and didn't have any issues, so thank you very much for the help.